# how do I add a node before the tail in doubly linked list?

Tags: c#, nodes, doubly-linked-list

Example: I got these nodes: 1, 2, 3, 3
Now I want to add another node: 3.
What happens now is: 1, 2, 3, 3, 3(new one).
But what I want is: 1, 2, 3(new one), 3, 3
What to do?

```
    if (H == null)
        {
            H = N;
            T = N;
        }
        else if (H.freq >= freq) //add before the header
        {
            N.next = H;
            H.prev = N;
            H = N;
        }
        else if (T.freq < freq) // add after the tail
        {
            N.prev = T;
            T.next = N;
            T = N;
        }
        else //merge between head and tail
        {
            W = H;
            while (freq > W.freq)
            {
                W = W.next;
            }
            N.next = W;
            N.prev = W.prev;
            W.prev.next = N;
            W.prev = N;
        }
```

Comment: It looks like it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Find` and `AddAfter` methods:

```
LinkedListNode<int> node = linked.Find(2);
linked.AddBefore(node, 3);
```

The main point is to use [`AddAfter`](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mdsn%20add%20after&gws_rd=ssl#q=mdsn%20addafter%20doublelinkedlist) method.

Comment: If you have a list: 1,2,2,3,3, this will insert it between the two 2's: 1,2,3,2,3,3 So, you'd rather do `Find(3)` and use `AddBefore()`.

Comment: Shouldn't you rather search for `3` and use [`AddBefore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw7zze8(v=vs.110).aspx)?